# ASUS laptop not using dedicated graphics card after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: graphics-card

I recently got my sister's old laptop.

Specs:

- Manufacturer: ASUS
- Model Name: X522E
- Processor: AMD Quad COre 1.5GHz
- RAM: 8GB
- Integrated/Onboard Graphics: HD Radeon 8330M
- Discrete/Dedicated Graphics: HD 8670M 1GB

I had upgraded it to Windows 10 and started to do some gaming when I realized that the laptop was using its onboard graphics card instead of the dedicated graphics card. I hunted for drivers, as I thought that the main card's drivers were out of date, but the games were still not registering the main GPU. I heard I can change the dedicated graphics card to default in BIOS, but I can't find any option in my BIOS to do so. I checked Device Manager and I could see both cards there, so I tried disabling the onboard card with no results. I also heard of changing it in the registry, but I am afraid to do that because if I mess up I can cause bigger problems. I'm not sure what to do next - please help me!

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS as well and noticed the same thing. I am however running windows 8 but that shouldn't matter all that much. To solve this, I have the control panel for my GFX card. You should have some form of software that changes the settings of your radeon GFX card, no? I am running an Nvidia card so I have Nvidia control panel but in there you should be able to select what program runs with what card. There is a global "default" setting that you could change to always use the Radeon, or you can specify your programs to run on whichever card. Hope that helps.

Comment: I tired using the amd version to that and I still unable to select an alternate Gpu. I'm beginning to think they might work in crossfire and work with each other. I'm currently playing skyrim in high settings with added visual mods to make it more demanding and I'm still getting 28 to 40 fps